# control 3 Segmented

Tags: ios, controls, swift3, segmentedcontrol

am using Xcode 8.1 , swift 3.0

i have code  Segmented its work with 2 control

when i try add 3 its not working any idea what is wrong with my code

**this one work with 2 Segmented**

```
@IBAction func showComponent(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
   if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, animations: {
         self.containerViewA.alpha = 1
         self.containerViewB.alpha = 0
      })     
   } else {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, animations: {
         self.containerViewA.alpha = 0
         self.containerViewB.alpha = 1
      })
   } 
}
```

**this one not working with 3 Segmented**

here am trying new code with 3x Segmented control;

```
@IBAction func showComponent(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
   if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
         self.containerViewA.alpha = 1
         self.containerViewB.alpha = 0
         self.containerViewC.alpha = 0
      })

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
         self.containerViewA.alpha = 0
         self.containerViewB.alpha = 1
         self.containerViewC.alpha = 0
   } else {     
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
         self.containerViewA.alpha = 0
         self.containerViewB.alpha = 0
         self.containerViewC.alpha = 1
      })
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i was trying with  this code its work now :)

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var orange: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var yellow: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var red: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func showComponent(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                self.orange.alpha = 1
              self.yellow.alpha = 0
                self.red.alpha = 0
        }
              if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                self.orange.alpha = 0
                 self.yellow.alpha = 1
               self.red.alpha = 0
        }
                if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
               self.orange.alpha = 0
                self.yellow.alpha = 0
                self.red.alpha = 1
          }
     }
}
```